# Using SQL, find all employee-transfers, so that avg. salary in both dep. and arr. departments grew

Tags: sql

Recently I was asked the following question on a entry-level programming interview, which never gave an answer, and Google is of little help.

> > Given: a table named 'employee'

```
 employee_id | name | salary | chief_id | department_id 
-------------+------+--------+----------+---------------
```

> > Only using SQL find all the variants of employee-transfers from one department to another, so that average salary in both 'departure' and 'arrival' department grew.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, but it is just a hint.

This is really asking which employee/department pairs are defined so that the employee has a smaller average salary than his/her current department but a larger salary than the average of the new department.

This is an example of the "ecological paradox", where the averages of both departments go up, even though the overall average clearly does not change.  I've heard this more in the vein of bad jokes:  "Did you hear about the guy who moved from Iowa to Minnesota, raising the average IQ of both states?"  (Note:  this is just an example of the paradox; the intention is not to cast aspersions on Iowans ;)